# Mission Control - JRockit on multiple machines..?

Tags: jrockit

I am new to Jrockit mission control so please bear with me.  I have 3 servers which are load balanced and are running JRockit. Can I use a single Management console to monitor all these servers and collate the information?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single JRockit Mission Control instance to connect to several servers at once. Each server will show up under it's own tab.

Documentation for JRockit Mission Control can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/index.htm